# Limit autocompletion on already seen tokens

Tags: autocomplete, pydev, outline

let the code speak:

```
$ cat Test3.py
def fun1():
    print "I'm in fun1"

$ cat Test2.py
import Test3 as T
T.fun1() # fine 
T.fun1   # bad
```

I edit Test2.py. When I press "T." pydev gives me some completion hints. It includes one method fun1(). That's good.
Then, when I do that for second time, pydev gives me two choices. A method, as before, and "something" called fun1 with no parentheses, just plain name with simple white circle icon. I couldn't find what does the icon mean (nor meaning of any other icon, to be honest) and a way to disable the second autocompletion, as useless in my case.
I use Eclipse 3.8/4.2 with Pydev 1.7.something on Linux and MS Windows.

Does anybody know a way to disable unnecessary part of autocompletion?

Regards,
Robert

Thank you for your answer.
However, the icon is different (white with dark circle).
I've downloaded pydev source code and it resembles PARAMETER_OBJ or similar thing - I don't know what to do further.
Please look at the screenshot
[image: Outline screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The icon indicates a visibility of the attribute or method:

[image]